# How to post an existing shapefile datastore using cURL?

Tags: shapefile, rest, curl, geoserver-rest-api

I read geoserver doc, and already Uploaded a shapefile to geoserver using cURL. But I can't change layer name by REST. So I think that there is another way to post a layer.
If I can post an existing shapefile datastore, this problem will be solved.

and is it possible change layer name(not title) by cURL?

This is my command line:

```
F:\\new\\curl-7.22.0\\src\\DLL-Release\\curl.exe -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type:text/xml" -d "file:///data/shapefiles/states.shp" http://********:8081/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/datastores/16-43/external.shp
```